Handling Errors in Batch Updates with NamedParameterJdbcTemplate
I'm currently working on a java batch where I need to execute batch updates using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate in Spring. I'm using the following code snippet to perform the batch execution:
java code:
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(eachSqlUpdateQueries, batchParams.toArray(new SqlParameterSource[0]))

However, I've run into an issue: the batchUpdate method does not provide detailed information about which specific records failed during execution with respective error message. This lack of error handling makes it challenging to troubleshoot issues when some records do not update successfully.
Note: I don't want to update each record individually due to performance issue.
Note: I am using MySQL database and  batchUpdate method only returns last failed record error message. However I want each failed record's reason of failure.
My questions:

Is there a way to capture detailed error information for each record that fails during the batch update?
Are there any recommended practices for handling such scenarios in Spring JDBC?

Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
I am expecting i keep each failed records failed cause or error message so put in logs

In case of an error the batchUpdate() method will break the processing and throw an appropriate exception. It will NOT continue to process the remaining statements.
The exception message you get is the one you can use for your logs. Additionally you cen get the count of successfully processed statements from the exception. This way you can determine which statement failed. It is the COUNT+1 statement.
Example of error handling:
} catch (BatchUpdateException e) {
    LOGGER.info(
        "Batch has managed to process {} statements",
         e.getUpdateCounts().length
    );
    LOGGER.info(
        "The {}. statement failed with error: {}",
         e.getUpdateCounts().length + 1,
         e.getMessage()
    );
}


e.getMessage() - only thrown last failed record exception , not each records which are failed in Batch.

Did you read my answer? Batch will break immediately after the first error.
